# Unable to initialize provider. Missing or incorrect schema in MYSQL

Tags: asp.net, mysql

Hi to all I have using MySQl Membership I am getting Error Unable to initialize provider. Missing or incorrect schema in MYSQL

```
       <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
       <providers>
      <clear />
<add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" autogenerateschema="true" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider,MySql.Web, Version=6.4.3.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="MyBusinessCalendar" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="5" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""  />
  </providers>
 </membership>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably help you out....

http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/02/how-to-setup-and-configure-mysql-membership-provider-6-2-2-porting-to-mono-part-2-of-3/